# Changing database in already exported .sql.gz file

Tags: mysql, zcat

So I have an exported database `database.sql.gz` from a database I can't access personally. Simply uploading it into PHPMyAdmin gives errors, and uploading it with `zcat {directory} | mysql -u {user} -p {database}` also gives an error "Row size too large (> 8126)". After reading through the file with Vi, I realize I can't simply change some row file formats around to make it fit, as the specific table has 67 rows. I also found out this table (along with others) don't get filled at all and get dropped at the end of the document. I tried commenting out the CREATE TABLE of the too large table, and there don't seem to have been any related errors from that, but I did run into some different errors at CREATE ALGORITHM commands.

Long story short, is there a better way to remove this giant table from my file that doesn't include exporting it again (as I don't have direct access to the database) or commenting out every bit that has to do with that table.

Comment: Here's [how to comment something out](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comments.html).

Comment: Yeah, I know how to comment things out. The issue is that there's too much to sift through. The text file containing the SQL is 3 GB large with well over a million lines. I need something that can sift through the file for me and remove all comments related to the specific table

Comment: There usually isn't that much to do when you want to comment out a table. The file size is not an indication of that. There are editors that can handle files of that size with ease. For instance: [010 editor](https://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/), but there are others.